# Combine meta query and give a specific meta query a higher priority

Tags: post-meta, meta-query

there is this loop which sorts by the date. But I want to throw in a specific meta key for a even higher priority. The meta_key "high_prio" should move it to the top of the sorting.
(I hope that makes sence).

Let's speak some code:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'event',
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'cat' => '4',
      'orderby' => array( 'meta_start' => 'ASC','meta_prio' => 'DESC'),
      'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        'meta_start' => array(
          'key' => 'date_start',
          'type' => 'numeric'
        ),
        'meta_prio' => array(
          'key' => 'high_prio',
          'type' => 'numeric'
        )
      )
    ));
```

The SQL looks like this now:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS pdh50NA5_posts.ID
FROM pdh50NA5_posts
LEFT JOIN pdh50NA5_term_relationships
ON (pdh50NA5_posts.ID = pdh50NA5_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN pdh50NA5_postmeta
ON ( pdh50NA5_posts.ID = pdh50NA5_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
AND ( pdh50NA5_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (4) )
AND ( pdh50NA5_postmeta.meta_key = 'date_start'
OR pdh50NA5_postmeta.meta_key = 'high_prio' )
AND pdh50NA5_posts.post_type = 'event'
AND (pdh50NA5_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR pdh50NA5_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled'
OR pdh50NA5_posts.post_status = 'private')
GROUP BY pdh50NA5_posts.ID
ORDER BY CAST(pdh50NA5_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) ASC, CAST(pdh50NA5_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 0, 3
```

I am not good at SQL. I understand the basics but the **order** part is too much.

Maybe this has to be done differently.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried switching the `orderby` items: `'orderby' => array('meta_prio' => 'DESC', 'meta_start' => 'ASC),` ?

Comment: You gave me an idea to check if the orderby even works after the many updates I did. I just posted an update.

Comment: And have you tried my suggestion? Did it work? If not, what's the output of `echo $loop->request;`?

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, I've updated the code and added the SQL.

Comment: And I've posted an answer. I hope it helps. Let me know. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue has been the **relation**. Of course, it must be "AND"

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'event',
      'posts_per_page' => 3,
      'cat' => '4',
      'orderby' => array('meta_prio' => 'DESC', 'meta_start' => 'ASC'),
      'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => '**AND**',
        'meta_start' => array(
          'key' => 'date_start',
          'type' => 'numeric'
        ),
        'meta_prio' => array(
          'key' => 'high_prio',
          'type' => 'numeric'
        )
      )
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

As I already pointed in the comment, all you need to do is change your `orderby` parameter so that the `meta_prio` is the first item and followed by the `meta_start`. So your `orderby` should look like:

```php
// This array forms an ORDER BY clause with each array item being a column that
// MySQL use when sorting the posts/results.
'orderby' => array(
    // This is the first column, which has the highest priority and sorts by the
    // meta high_prio.
    'meta_prio'  => 'DESC',

    // This is the second column, which sorts by the meta date_start, after MySQL
    // sort the results by the meta high_prio.
    'meta_start' => 'ASC',
)
```

So with the above example, the generated `ORDER BY` clause would look something like `ORDER BY <meta_prio column> DESC, <meta_start column> ASC` and MySQL would first sort the results by the `high_prio` meta and then sort the **sorted** results by the `date_start` meta.

And remember that the *array key* used in your `orderby` must match the one in your `meta_query`, if you're sorting the results by the meta query clauses in the `meta_query` array. Additionally, make sure you set the proper `type` in your meta query clauses; e.g. if the value is a date like `2020-03-12 09:30`, then you'd set the type to `DATETIME` (i.e. `'type' => 'DATETIME'`):

```php
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation'   => 'OR',
    'meta_start' => array(
        'key'  => 'date_start',
        'type' => 'DATETIME',
    ),
    'meta_prio'  => array(
        'key'  => 'high_prio',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    )
),
// Make sure the array keys match those in the above meta_query array.
'orderby'    => array(
    'meta_prio'  => 'DESC',
    'meta_start' => 'ASC',
),
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. In my first attempt I had the matching correct, but at the end I copied it wrong. 
I understand the orderby method, first sort by x and then after y.
But it does not work. 
If i use "order by meta_start" it sorts by the date (unix, numeric), if I add "meta_prio" like in your example, the sorting is wrong. It sorts by meta_prio but not by meta_start any more.

Comment: I got it, 'relation' => 'AND', was the issue. I had "OR". After finding the issue, it makes sence now. Thx you helped me anyway.

Comment: Alright then, but the answer did answer the "give a specific meta query a *higher* priority" as in the question and the `relation` has nothing to do with the `ORDER BY` clause itself - the `relation` plays the main part in the `WHERE` clause. And I'm sure it does  - "It sorts by meta_prio but not by meta_start any more" - you're just not `SELECT`-ing the proper posts. So if the answer is not acceptable, you can post your own answer and accept your answer so others know the question has an accepted solution. Cheers!